# Starting PostgreSQL with RoR Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to get my ruby on rails application to work using PostgreSQL but cannot figure out what the problem is. I'm working on this app with another person, they're on MacOS and I'm on Windows 10. Would us working cross-platform be a problem? As far as I know, everything is installed but it's still not working. Here are some of the errors I get.

1. sudo service postgresql start

- No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"

2. rails db:setup
   /home/blah/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/ruby: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems
   FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "AppUser"
   Couldn't create 'myapp_development' database. Please check your configuration.
   rails aborted!
   PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "AppUser"
   /mnt/c/users/blah/desktop/project/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>' /mnt/c/users/blah/desktop/project/myapp/bin/spring:15:in` <top (required)>'
   bin/rails:3:in `load' bin/rails:3:in` '
   Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => db:create
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

I know 100% for a fact that my password is correct. I even made sure to change it in pgadmin in case I was misremembering. I reinstalled postgresql with the same password for the postgres account, master password, and this user password and it still doesn't work.

3. sudo ps aux | grep postgres
   [sudo] password for blah:
   blah    228  0.3  0.0  16208  1284 tty1     S    13:05   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres

I would appreciate any help in getting this started. Thank you!!

Comment: Have you checked if `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` happens to be set and has a password parameter? It will override any settings in `database.yml`.

Comment: I can't find ENV['DATABASE_URL'] anywhere. Where should that be located?